# JavaScript regular expression for two-letter tokens separated by commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get the regular expression that accepts only characters with specific pattern like two characters separated by comma, but I am not able to get it.

Here i included the acceptable sting

```
string = ab,ca,ls,gz,tv......
```

I tried:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]{2},)|([a-zA-Z]{2})*$/
```

but it is not working as expected.

Comment: This `[a-zA-Z]{2},|[a-zA-Z]{2}` won't work when it's unconstrained. For example it matches `ab`cdef, and ab`cd`ef, before it matches abcd`ef,` Essentially, it's equivalent to `[a-zA-Z]{2},?`

Comment: To get all values, it's better to split on `,` get into an array, then filter the array for 2 char's if you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`/^[a-z]{2}(?:,[a-z]{2})*$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/0iORRL/1) instead (the `|` inside your pattern was problematic):

```js
var string = 'ab,ca,ls,gz,tv'

var regex = /^[a-z]{2}(?:,[a-z]{2})*$/i

console.log(regex.test(string)) //=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then you're trying to get (capture) the 2 characters, with the condition that they're within the bounds of a comma or at the start or end of a line:

```
(?:^|,)([a-zA-Z]{2})(?=,|$)
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/5Bmq9c/1)

```js
var string = "ab,ca,ls,gz,tv";

const regex = /(?:^|,)([a-zA-Z]{2})(?=,|$)/g;

match = regex.exec(string);

while (match != null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(string);
}
```

The above outputs:

> ab
>
> ca
>
> ls
>
> gz
>
> tv

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
/^[a-z]{2}(,[a-z]{2})*$/i
```

```js
var string1 = "ab,ca,ls,gz,tv"
var string2 = "ab,c,ls"
var string3 = "ab,ca"

var regex = /^[a-z]{2}(,[a-z]{2})*$/i

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 
    regex.test(string1) + "<br>" + // true
    regex.test(string2) + "<br>" + // false
    regex.test(string3)            // true
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
```